# Youtube micro stuttering 18.04 lts

Tags: drivers, display-resolution, amd-graphics, youtube

I had the same problem back in 2011 with an Asus eee pc and I never managed to solved it, in the end I figured it's because there is no official drivers from the manufacturer.

Now I did a fresh install of 18.04 on a E8400, P5Q-PRO, 4gb ddr2 800mhz, Radeon 5750 512mb that used to run YouTube on Windows 10 without a problem. The only thing that's different is I changed the hard drive from a 7200 rpm to a 5400 rpm and the screen from a 1240 x 1024 to a 42"1080p Sony Bravia television.

My question is if youtube microstuttering is because of my hardware , if it's too old for that kind of resolution or if it's a software problem i can fix .

What I have tried so far:

- firefox
- chromium
- enabling/disabling hardware acceleration
- changing the screen hz

The only thing after extensive search i haven't tried is using an older kernel.

Should I try a lighter distro like lubuntu? Will I see any difference?

Comment: If you fixed the hardware acceleration in about:config and you have the proper driver's, then I'd look into the latency timers and the Irq interrupts, have you used gdb or strace when you used Firefox to determine your problem, you could probably use strace with egrep parameters like strace firefox | egrep error\|fault\|corrupt\|delay\|missing\|freeze whem Latency times hold a PCI bus to long it causes others to lag in video, audio, etc

Comment: Aside from that, have a peek at pulse audio, remove it and use alsa, your problem may just be pulses file being corrupt or too, full, or it could be that its just not my type of program lol